# Initialize AngularJS Model From HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I'm working with django + angular. I'd like django to populate a value in the HTML template, and then tell Angular to use that value as initial value for a model.

I need this for two reasons:

1. **Simplicity** - The page deos not currently use Angular, and I believe
   it would be
       easier to upgrade this way.
2. **SEO** - Some search engines can't read
       values populated in the DOM through Angular. I know there are
       several solutions for SEO with Angular but I hope there's an easier
       way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Yes, you can do this, but still not sure what the problem is.

Comment: The usual way is using {{scope.model}}, which populates the HTML from Angular. I'd like to do it the other way around. Set a value in a regular HTML tag and then have Angular read & update that value as usual

Comment: `<div ng-bind="model"></div>`?

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize you model based on that initial HTMl value.

For instance your HTML would be:

```
<div ng-bind="value">initialValue</div>
```

And you controller:

```
var elem = $( 'get the element' );
$scope.value = elem.text();
```

Angular will then take over and can reflect any change made to `$scope.value`.

The downside is that you need to grab the element (using jQuery here for simplicity but you can use vanilla Javascript).

One way to work around that would be a custom directive:

```
<div late-binding="value">initialValue</div>
```

I let the directive code as an exercice to the reader, unless you need help for it :)

Comment: Thanks! This sounds right. I'll give it a try & hopefully accept!